# transitionDuration as of jQuery 1.11.1 requires "0ms" instead of 0, by design or bug?

Tags: jquery, css, transition

When first applying a transition duration of a given time, say "250ms", and afterwards setting the transition duration to 0 ([meaning there will be no effect](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transitionduration.asp)), jQuery (as of 1.11.1) still keeps the original transition duration of "250ms" (see fiddles). **When settings the duration to "0ms" (instead of 0), it acts accordingly (no transition duration takes place). Is this by design or a bug?** A.k.a. should I report it ;)

```
var duration = "250ms";

$("#dot").on("click", function(){

    $(this).css({
        transitionDuration: duration,
        transitionTimingFunction: "ease",
        transform: 'translate3d(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1 + 'px, ' 
                                  + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1 + 'px, 0px)'
    }).text( duration );

    duration = 0;

});
```

[transitionDuration, set to 0 after 1 click (**works**) jquery **1.11.0**](http://jsfiddle.net/wfmdqz4f/11/)

[transitionDuration, set to 0 after 1 click (**bug?**) jquery 1.11.1](http://jsfiddle.net/wfmdqz4f/7/)

[transitionDuration, set to "0ms" after 1 click (***fix***) jquery 1.11.1](http://jsfiddle.net/wfmdqz4f/8/)